# Div Is Not Aligning Left Any Further on Mobile Site

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, web-frontend, mobile-website

I'm creating a mental health website from its desktop version and I wanted to align a div to the left side for the mobile view. Within the div, there is an input text field and two buttons as part of a CSS flexbox. I am using @media.

Here's how the div contents look like on the mobile screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVyXJ.jpg)

I want to shift the div contents so that is align with the paragraph text above the white input text field.

I tried using margin-left and align-items to manipulate the div but it does not shift to the left far enough. I then tried using margin-left and margin-right to manually manipulate the div, but the buttons began to stretch instead of retaining their size.

Here's my original HTML code for the desktop version:

```
<p class="angryText">sample text</p>
  <div id="containerAngry">
    <input class="input" id="angryInput">
    <button onclick="angry()" style="text-align:left; margin-left: 2em; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 1em;" id="breathingCircleButton">Submit</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('angryInput').value = ''; document.getElementById('angry').innerHTML = '';"
      style="text-align:left; margin-left: 2em; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 1em;" id="breathingCircleButton">Clear input field</button>
  </div>

  <p id="angry"></p>
  <script>
    function angry() {
      document.getElementById("angry").innerHTML = "I understand. You have every right to feel the way you do and it's frustrating.";
    }
  </script>
```

Here's my CSS for all of the div elements:

```
.input {
  margin-left: 2.5em;
  background-color: #F7F5FB;
  color: #1B9AAA;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 1em 1em;
}

#breathingCircleButton {
  border: none;
  background-color: #1B9AAA;
  color: #F7F5FB;
  padding-left: 1.5%;
  padding-right: 1.5%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 12px;
  float: left;
}

#containerAngry {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  column-gap: 0.5em;
  align-items: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  #containerAngry {
    margin-left: 5%;
}
}
```

Thank you for any feedback and help!

Comment: `padding: 1%` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: You need to clean-up your styles - you've got `#id` selectors on some rules, but then overriding those with inline `style=""` attributes. Use one or the other.

Comment: The input and buttons aren't left aligned because you have left margins on them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use min-width instead of max-width and give margin only after screen size above  850px.

Check below code on mobile browser. content align properly to the left side


    .input {
     
      background-color: #F7F5FB;
      color: #1B9AAA;
      border: none;
      font-size: 1em;
      width: 25%;
      padding: 1em 1em;
    }

    #breathingCircleButton {
      border: none;
      background-color: #1B9AAA;
      color: #F7F5FB;
      padding-left: 1.5%;
      padding-right: 1.5%;
      padding-top: 1%;
      padding-bottom: 1%;
      text-align: left;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      margin-bottom: 2em;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
      border-radius: 12px;
      float: left;
    }

    #containerAngry {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      column-gap: 0.5em;
      align-items: left;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 850px) {
      #containerAngry {
        margin-left: 5%;
      }
        input{
        margin-left:2.5em;
        }
        #breathingCircleButton{
            margin-left:2.5em;
        }
    }
 

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <p class="angryText">sample text</p>
    <div id="containerAngry">
      <input class="input" id="angryInput">
      <button onclick="angry()" style="text-align:left;  margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 1em;" id="breathingCircleButton">Submit</button>
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('angryInput').value = ''; document.getElementById('angry').innerHTML = '';" style="text-align:left; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 1em;" id="breathingCircleButton">Clear input field</button>
    </div>

    <p id="angry"></p>
    <script>
      function angry() {
        document.getElementById("angry").innerHTML = "I understand. You have every right to feel the way you do and it's frustrating.";
      }
    </script>

<!-- end snippet -->
```